# toilet bubbling

Tags: plumbing

I recently added a basement sink next to the vent pipe, now I have bubbling in my upstairs toilet, sink and water backing up in my upstairs shower when my basement pump kicks on?  could it be my vent or a blockage somewhere?

Comment: It could be a blockage in the main vent pipe or in the waste line.  Just a thought.